# Spotify Play Button track set limit?

Tags: spotify

I'm playing with the spotify play button and try to make it display an arbitrary set of tracks, that I'm giving as a comma-separated list of IDs.

It works well most of the time, but it can happen that the button is not properly rendered, and displays the Spotify Developer Page instead, like shown here: http://xben.free.fr/spotify/

I feel like it happens when using an important number of tracks (more than 80).

Has one of you experienced the same problem, or know if there is a limitation? I went through the doc and it only mentions a 1000 tracks restriction when using an existing playlist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is known limitation that trackset uris can not be longer than around 80 tracks (depending on your trackset title).

The reasoning for the arbitrary limit goes something like this: It is the longest possible url that you can send to older IE browsers. We want it to work the same across all browsers. If it doesn't work in one, it shouldn't work in the others either.

Two problems however.

The way it is implemented, just setting suhosin.get.max_value_length = 2048 in php conf. If it is too big, suhosin will just drop the parameter, making the request look like https://embed.spotify.com which will redirect to the developer site. Not the best of error messages. We will fix.

The limit should be documented. We will fix. Maybe even raise the limit and tell people to be vary of certain browsers.

(I work at Spotify)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I should have guessed it's linked to the url size rather than the number of tracks in the playlist. I will split the playlist into smaller ones, or create an real playlist to get a playlist URI.