# Ajax Iframe creation (Spotify widget): x-frame error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, spotify

I'm trying to dyanmically populate a spotify trackset widget with ajax after sending a get request to an API endpoint that returns spotify track uris.

The url that is created works fine when loaded in a browser, and the iframe loads fine when its hardcode into the webpage. However if I dynamically generate the source url with ajax, Spotify throws this error:

> Refused to display 'https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Here is the ajax/jquery get request:

```
                $('a#generate-playlist').bind('click', function() {
              $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_generate_playlist',{
                 uid: '{{ fb_user_id }}',
                 spotify_token: '{{ spotify_token }}'
              }, function(data) {
              $("#response").append($('<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:trackset:trackSetTitle:' + data.track_uris + '" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>'));
              });
```

This a working embed url that doesn't work when dynamically rendered:
[working spotify trackset](https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:trackset:trackSetTitle:3AhXZa8sUQht0UEdBJgpGc,1lqMLr9Wj7SM2F9AikGcxN,6HSXNV0b4M4cLJ7ljgVVeh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the number of tracks in your 'trackset' to under 80 and it works fine. I have had trouble with the same error message.

Though I can't find spotify docs stating this, it seems to be confirmed here by a spotify developer: [Spotify Play Button track set limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502275/spotify-play-button-track-set-limit).